# Spring MVC: No qualifying bean of type found for dependency using @component

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have this class on a jar

```
package com.tdk.iot;


@Component
public class LogTemplate {
..
}
```

this is my application context file:

```
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.tdk.iot" />
```

But when I start the application I have this error:

```
weblogic.application.ModuleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.tdk.iot.LogTemplate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Comment: I would not recommend mixing annotations and xml.

Comment: If your LogTemplate class is auto-wiring some other class and it is not in the package "com.tdk.iot" then you need to add those package scan into your xml component-scan

Comment: Can you show LogTemplate fully...or atleast till declaration of class level variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to declare the bean explicitly

```
<bean id="logTemplate" class="org.tdk.iot.LogTemplate"/>
```

Also make sure that your jar is really on classpath.